# Like query on TEXT data type field (postgres) in spring JpaRepository

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have an object `NewsItem` in my Postgres database with field `body` which is  TEXT data type and  [image: column contains only IDs.]

I want to perform Like query using JpaRepository.

```
select * from news.news_item newsitem where lower(convert_from(loread(lo_open(newsitem.body::int, x'40000'::int), x'40000'::int),  'UTF8')) like lower(('%'||'query'||'%'));
```

^This query in pgAdmin returns correct result.
How can I convert this query to work in Spring JpaRepository?

Comment: Use javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery annotation to declare your query on entity or repository. Make sure to specify resultClass in NamedQuery. In your case it is NewsItem.class. It can not be done in generic way as sql uses pgsql functions. Another way is to introduce full text search using Lucene, solr or elasticSearch but it may be too heavy weight. If you are using hibernate already, you can take look at hibernate search and [integration with Spring](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/11/23/spring-boot-and-hibernate-search-integration/)

Comment: @SangramJadhav thanks! it worked. I've also changed ::int casting to  cast as int and added Transactional annotation